# How to transfer incoming call to main agent after talking a little with incoming caller Id in twillio?

Tags: php

I have a web app which uses Twillio as a call service, so how can I transfer incoming call after identifying incoming caller to main agent?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make two queues, one before identifying and one is after. so when having a call in before, then you transfer it to the after queue, and then you can pull the calls from that queue